# Check solutions for this integral $\oint_\Gamma \frac{3z -1}{(z+2i)^3 z^2} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

$$\oint_\Gamma \frac{3z -1}{(z+2i)^3 z^2}  dz$$

Here $\Gamma$ is the circle $|z| = 1/2$ traveling once counterclockwise

$$\oint_\Gamma \frac{\frac{3z -1}{(z+2i)^3}} {z^2}  dz$$

$$= 2\pi i \frac{d}{dz} \frac{3z - 1}{(z+2i)^3} \big|_{z=0}$$

$$= 2\pi i \left(\frac{-24i - 12}{-64}\right)$$

Comment: Don't forget to mention [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) and simplify further (common factor of $4$). Looks good otherwise.